# Allow-navigation on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a cordova app for Android and iOS. The app is a mobile website that loads in the webview. When a user clicks a link, that is outside the mobile website, I want the link opened in the system browser.

Now on Android this works fine with allow-navigation. iOS it's not.

```
<allow-navigation href="https://mywebsite.nl/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://code.jquery.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://use.fontawesome.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="*.google.com" />
<allow-navigation href="*.googleapis.com" />
<allow-navigation href="*.gstatic.com" />
<allow-navigation href="*.googleusercontent.com" />
<allow-navigation href="google.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="googleapis.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="gstatic.com/*" />
<allow-navigation href="googleusercontent.com/*" />
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
<allow-navigation href="*youtube*" />
<allow-navigation href="*ytimg*" />
<allow-navigation href="*youtube-nocookie*" />
<allow-navigation href="*vimeo*" />
<access origin="https://*.youtube-nocookie.com" />
<access origin="https://*.youtube.com" />
<access origin="*.vimeo.com" />
<access origin="*.vimeocdn.com" />
<access origin="https://*.ytimg.com" />
<access origin="https://*.gstatic.com" />
<access origin="https://*.googlevideo.com" />
<access origin="https://*.google.com" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

Do I need to add something for iOS to open the system browser when clicking an external link?

Comment: What's your specific code you use to open a new window? And are you using InAppBrowser? See https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/#cordovainappbrowseropen

Comment: I don't use a specific code to open a new window, just <a href="url">..</a>. I'm not using the InAppBrowser. But this is all working fine on Android.